# jQuery scrollTop not working (repeats over and over again) for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have the following code that I am using to scroll to the top of the page. It works great, except on my android phone. When "a" is clicked (on android browser) the page scrolls to the top as expected, but whenever I try to scroll back down the page, the animation starts up again even though the event does not appear to be triggered again and the page scrolls up to the top.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
});
```

Anyone know why the animation happens again and how I can stop it?

Comment: It could be your `a` element is large (in css) and when you scroll down, your actually clicking on the link again.

Comment: No, that's it. The click event is not being fired again. It is just the animate that is being fired.

Answer (score 0):

I'm silly, Apparently I was calling the animate() somewhere else in my code. :(